# Genus of a simple graph $G$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph with set of vertices $V(G)=\{a_i,v_j \mid 1\leq i \leq 5, 1\leq j \leq 4\}$ and the set of edges is $E(G)=\{a_ra_s,v_1v_2,v_1v_3,v_1v_4,v_1a_1,v_1a_2,v_1a_3,v_2a_1,v_2a_4,v_2a_5,v_3a_2,v_3a_4,v_3a_5,v_4a_3,v_4a_4,v_4a_5 \mid r,s\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}, r\neq s\}$.

What is the genus of this graph? The genus of the graph $G$ is either one or two, but i could not show whether it is one or two. Thanks for any help.